# Knex saves date incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, node-postgres

I have a date field set with `table.date('day');` in knex schema. When I insert it with `knex('table_name').insert({ someOtherData, day: '2016-08-14'})` and then use `knex.select('day').from('table_name')` I get `[Date: 2016-08-13T22:00:00.000Z]`. It seems as if it saves it as '2016-08-14T00:00:00.000Z' and then subtracts 2 hours to conver it into UTC.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be because of time zone conversion. Have you tried using timestamp?

```
    table.timestamp('response_deadline')
```

It will convert date **datatype** to **timestamp with time zone**.

Answer (score 0):

the docs on [schema building](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-date) seems vague however try to deliver this date string to a js date constructor, i'm pretty sure it will deliver you the correct date.

it tries to represent every date as the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) recommends, that's why you're seeing the date this way.